what would the oracle sql query be to split values in columns?
I want to split values i a column into n sections considering ~ as the delimiter. And I want to do this for all values in that column assuming the length of characters of each section changes.
lets take '147 Spadina Ave~Toronto~CA' as a value in a column. I want to split them into n sections considering ~ as the delimiter. And I want to do this all values in that column assuming the length of characters of each section changes.
'147 Spadina Ave~Toronto~CA' should be split into 3 different strings like below
147 Spadina Ave
Toronto
CA
like this lets say the length changes, for eg next row instead of Toronto it is Vancouver then it should split into
147 Spadina Ave
Vancouver
CA

Use REGEXP_SUBSTR for as many times as you need.
SELECT 
   REGEXP_SUBSTR(T1.COLUMN_NAME, '[^~]+', 1, 1) Col_1,
   REGEXP_SUBSTR(T1.COLUMN_NAME, '[^~]+', 1, 2) Col_2,
   REGEXP_SUBSTR(T1.COLUMN_NAME, '[^~]+', 1, 3) Col_3,
   REGEXP_SUBSTR(T1.COLUMN_NAME, '[^~]+', 1, 4) Col_4
FROM TABLE_NAME T1;


Is it possible to get the same using just the substr function?

Not that's as simple as this. You can use SUBSTR however you'll need to know the position of the next '~' and if it changes depending on the string it won't work.
